# Kafka's exactly-once-semantics producer side

Tags: apache-kafka

I was looking at https://dzone.com/articles/interpreting-kafkas-exactly-once-semantics

Good article, though a question remains.

To guarantee idempotency on the Producer side of KAFKA for exactly-once-semantics:

- is it sufficient to use the producer.Props.put("enable.idempotence", "true") set to true?
- or, do we also have to use the producer.commitTransaction **as well**? Or, only if partitioned?

Unclear from article. I think there is an issue in the article. PID could change after re-start of Producer.

I am not sure if 'committed' approach gets rid of this problem from reading the article, I think not, as it is a different aspect. So, again the guarantee stated is not a hard one imho. Looking for confirmation.

Comment: Also relevant https://medium.com/@andy.bryant/processing-guarantees-in-kafka-12dd2e30be0e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only half of the equation - and looking at it from Spark / KAFKA Integration perspective:

**End-to-end Fault Tolerance**

Structured Streaming ensures end-to-end exactly-once fault-tolerance guarantees through *check-pointing* and *Write Ahead Logs*.

Structured Streaming sources, sinks, and the underlying execution engine work together to track the progress of stream processing. If a failure occurs, the streaming engine attempts to restart and/or reprocess the data.

This approach only works if the streaming source is replayable. To ensure fault-tolerance, Structured Streaming assumes that every streaming source has offsets, akin to:

- Kafka message offsets
- Kinesis sequence numbers

At a high level, the underlying streaming mechanism relies on a couple approaches:

- First, Structured Streaming uses check-pointing and write-ahead logs to record the offset range of data being processed during each trigger interval.
- Next, the streaming sinks are designed to be idempotent—that is, multiple writes of the same data (as identified by the offset) do not result in duplicates being written to the sink.

Taken together, re-playable data sources and idempotent sinks allow Structured Streaming to ensure end-to-end, exactly-once semantics under any failure condition.

The Sink aspect means that we need 2 things taken into account.